Remount system partition for read and write permission without Magisk installed on a rooted Android 13
I have a rooted Android 13 device with dm-verity disabled. How can I remount the system partition for read and write permission without Magisk installed?

You need some kind of software to manage root level access while the system is running,  otherwise "root" means nothing in the GUI so Magisk or a similar tool is required. Are you trying to do this on an active running device or from a recovery tool like TWRP?
